# CSS animation-fill-mode and z-index issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, z-index, css-animations

I'm using CSS animations (from animate.css) in a project I'm working on.
What I found out is that when fading in a container with an absolutely positioned and z-indexed child in it, the z-index of the child isn't working as it should.

I recreated the issue in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lxsf9ako/

The issue seems to be caused by

```
animation-fill-mode: both;
```

This style is placed on the container by animate.css, thus I have no control over this. I could overwrite it by using `animation-fill-mode: none`, but I rather don't do this for every animation.

Any ideas on this one?

**Update:**
I just found out this is webkit related, IE11 renders this correctly.

**Update 2:**
I can't edit the `.container` class on hover.

**Update 3:**
The 'hover' in the Fiddle is just a demo. In fact, the `.over` object is the popup from the angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker directive, and the `.container` elements are generic elements used throughout the application. Giving them an extra id/class to identify them as datepicker containers is not a clean solution for me.

Comment: you need change z-index on hover

Comment: you couuld add z-index:-1 to the second .container in your case like this > http://jsfiddle.net/Lxsf9ako/6/ || but as I see, your example is not your actual scenario so it's hard to tell.. try it.

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
#hoverme{
   z-index: 1;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxsf9ako/5/)**

### Why you have to do this

> Without any z-index value, elements stack in the order that they
>   appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level
>   appears on top). Elements with non-static positioning will always
>   appear on top of elements with default static positioning.
>
> Also note that nesting plays a big role. If an element B sits on top
>   of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than
>   element B.

[From css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

```css
#hoverme {
  z-index: 1;
}
.container {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fff), to(#efefef));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #efefef 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #efefef 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #efefef 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #efefef 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#efefef', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
#hoverme .over {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #efefef;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
#hoverme:hover .over {
  display: block;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hoverme" class="container">
  <div class="over">I should be over the next container</div>
</div>
<div class="container">I should be under the .over</div>
```

### Update

You could also use a transition on the `.over` with `opacity` and `visibility`.

```
#hoverme .over {
    opacity: 0; 
    visibility:hidden;
    transition:visibility 0.4s, opacity 0.4s; 
    ...
}

#hoverme:hover .over {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxsf9ako/10/)**

```css
.container {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fff), to(#efefef));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #efefef 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #efefef 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #efefef 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #efefef 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#efefef', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#hoverme .over {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #efefef;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
#hoverme:hover .over {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="hoverme" class="container">
  <div class="over">I should be over the next container</div>
</div>
<div class="container">I should be under the .over</div>
```

Comment: Hi,

Please see comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099421/css-animation-fill-mode-and-z-index-issue/26099518?noredirect=1#comment40900317_26099518

Comment: Well if you are using a framework (angular) this should work ootb. Something in your code seems to interfere here.

Comment: The issue is a combination of the animate.css (http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) animations, in combination with the angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker directive.

It is an issue with the -webkit-animation-fill-mode css property in Chrome, IE11 renders this correctly.

Comment: true. Well may [this workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxsf9ako/9/) helps you. But here the message is just hidden by `opacity`. You could add some JS to get better results.

Comment: This removes the animation on the `.container` elements and places it on the `.over` element. I might try to find a fix using the `opacity` property to try and get the element back in the stacking order though, will keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `z-index` of the container on `hover`. Try this:

```
.container:hover {
    z-index:100;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Lxsf9ako/2/

Comment: Hey,

That does work indeed, but I can't do this in this specific case, the containers are a generic class used throughout the application, over which I have no control. The issue needs to be fixed on the overlay itself.

Comment: so you can't create tyour own css? @GerritBertier

Comment: I can, but the hover is actually just a demo case.

In fact, the 'overlay' is the popup from an angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker directive, and the container is a generic class. The popup should show upon clicking the datepicker button, and I don't want to add extra javascript unless really necessary.