# Z-index problem of dropdown menu inside a animated card

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, z-index, opacity

I have a problem that I've tried to simply in this stackblitz (the real project is made with angular components and bootstrap .. etc): 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-njixcw

When using a dropdown inside an faded animated card, the dropdown menu is behind, instead of being in front. (click the red dropdown to reproduce)

The dropdown with no animation works perfectly (click the green dropdown to reproduce).

It seems to me a problem with the opacity property, can anyone help me achieve the same result (keeping the animation) without the problem of the dropdown menu behind.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099421/css-animation-fill-mode-and-z-index-issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-pymj6s?file=src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding z-index:1 to .card-body